# Subscribing events in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events

I'm trying to convert some C# code to VB.NET.

I have the following in C# (which works)

```cs
m_switchImageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
m_switchImageTimer.Interval = Interval;
m_switchImageTimer.Tick += (s, e) => LoadNextImage();
```

The key line I'm struggling to convert successfully is:

```cs
m_switchImageTimer.Tick += (s, e) => LoadNextImage();
```

What I have tried is:

```
m_switchImageTimer.Tick += Function(s, e) LoadNextImage()
m_switchImageTimer.Tick += New EventHandler(AddressOf LoadNextImage)
```

Neither of these are working.

The first attempt produces two errors, the first VS2010 highlights under m_switchImageTimer.Tick:

> Error 1   'Public Event Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event

and highlighted under LoadNextImage() produces the following error:

> Error 3   Expression does not produce a value.

The second attempt produces the same error:

> Error 1   'Public Event Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

How can I convert the C# code to VB.NET?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Subscribing to events in VB.NET requires either the AddHandler or Handles keyword.  You will also have a problem with the lambda, the Function keyword requires an expression that returns a value.  In VS2010 you can write this:

```
    AddHandler m_switchImageTimer.Tick, Sub(s, e) LoadNextImage()
```

In earlier versions, you need to either change the LoadNextImage() method declaration or use a little private helper method with the correct signature:

```
    AddHandler m_switchImageTimer.Tick, AddressOf SwitchImageTimer_Tick
...
Private Sub SwitchImageTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    LoadNextImage()
End Sub
```